# images are overlapping on the other divs css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the create a search page, where when i add text in search panel the images of those text will display. The issue I am facing is that the images are overlapping on the search div even though I have positioned it well. 
[image]

I don't want to fix it using top values as I want the page to be responsive and the top values will be changing based on the width of the page. Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
</div>
<div id="search">
    <form>
       <input type="search" ng-model="vm.search.gif" value="" placeholder="type what you're looking for" />
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.performSearch()">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img ng-repeat="g in vm.giphies" ng-src="{{g.images.original.url}}">
</div>
```

css:

```
#body {
    width: 100%;
}
#search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 174px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 10;
}

#search input[type="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: -51px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    outline: none;
}
#search .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 61px;
    margin-left: -45px;
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the overflow on the card class to hidden(to hide the overlapping content) Or you can set it to auto( scroll bars appear if overlapping).

---

`.card{
  overflow: hidden;
 }`

Comment: I did try this solution before, but it doesn't fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Well you haven't positioned anything well there. Does everything really need the position property set to absolute? If so, try using JavaScript to get the search area's height (or set a fixed one) & apply it to the "top" property in the card.